# Is there a NAS adapter for USB drives?

Tags: data-storage, nas

I have a bunch of external hard drives, and I'm getting a bit tired of connecting and disconnecting them all the time - not to mention the noise. I'd like to find a way to connect them to my network instead so they can sit in a cabinet and stay out of my way.

Is there anything that could do that? Ideally wired, but wifi will do at a pinch. If it can take multiple drives, that'd be a bonus.

I'm not looking for a specific number of ports; four would be a good balance, twelve would be great if I find one that doesn't cost too much, but one would be fine too. No particular features or requirements in mind; I just want to be able to have some drives plugged in in another room so I can access them over the network.

Budget would be ideally below 1,000 SEK, but there's some leeway.

Comment: Does your router have USB ports?

Comment: It has one, yes, but there's no space in the internet cabinet (installed by the landlord, so I can't move or change it) for drives or more power supplies.

Comment: In my experience, many home routers have a usb port for sharing an external hard drive, BUT most inexpensive routers sharing feature is utterly awful. Actually copying files to/from this drive either completely broken or impractically slow (weeks-per-terabyte). So there's plenty of demand for a device like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addonics has introduced its Network Attached Storage (NAS) adapter, which is a $55 device that lets you plug a USB-powered external drive in one end and then connect an Ethernet cable to the other end that runs to your router.

http://www.zdnet.com/article/turn-external-hard-drives-into-network-storage-via-usb-with-addonics-nas-adapter/#!

http://www.addonics.com/products/nas40esu.php

Comment: Addonics stop selling that model. They have an enterprisy one for $89 USD plus postage, but that's more than most people spend on their router. They have nothing really suitable for budget home use.